# Почему save() не срабытывает?

Tags: yii2

Собственно вот сам код

```
$trailers=Trailers::findOne(['id_film'=>$film->id]);
       if(isset($trailers)) {
                    $trailers->description = $video;
                    $trailers->id_film = $film->id;
                    if($trailers->save()){}else{var_dump($trailers->getErrors());};
         }
```

в дебагере показывает, что такую запись находит но не сохраняет. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас срабатывает `var_dump($trailers->getErrors()`? Может быть несколько случаев: модель не прошла валидацию (попробуйте сначала вызвать `$trailers->validate()`), mysql-пользователь не может писать в БД и т.д. и т.п.

P.S. Не очень правильно называть переменную `$trailers`, когда вы ищите единственную запись с помощью `findOne()`. Назовите её `$trailer`, потом, через пару десятков строк кода будет гораздо очевиднее.

Comment: нет getErrors не срабатывает если код  сделать так 
                    $trailer=new Trailers([
                        'description'   =>  $video,
                        'id_film'       =>  $film->id,
                    ]);
                    $trailer->save();
                }  то новый сохранится.

Comment: название ведь сейчас не имеет значение

Comment: Нет, название не имеет значения, это так, на будущее.